# Kotlin: How to Observe Once a liveData in a viewModel ? Using ObserveForever() and removeObserver()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm learning Kotlin and I'm trying to use the same ViewModel for display a list of users and for edit of a user.

I'm using room so I have a "getPersonnelById() which needs to be Observed. The problem is that I would like to Observe only Once and I don't know how to do...

Here's my function

```
private fun retrievePersonnelData(id: Long){

    if(id != -1L){

     val observer = dataSource.getPersonnelById(id).observeForever{
            newPersonnel.value = it
            Timber.e("Valeur newPersonnel = ${newPersonnel.value}")
        }

    }
}
```

I've used as recommended a observeForever but I don't know how to use removeObserver in this case...

Thank you very much

Comment: use [LiveData Transformations](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata)

Comment: It worked thank you but then I need to put to observe it from my fagment and I don't think it's really clean in MVVM pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get data once - consider using [suspend functions in Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5) and get data by demand.

If you need to get a particular `Personnel` object and observe changes in DB of it, store value of `getPersonnelById(id)` in `LiveData<Personnel>` and observe it from Activity/Fragment

`observeForever` is mostly needed in testing purposes, you should better use [observe function](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects) to not manually remove an observer every time.